# Orchard CMS HQL Query Taxonomies : OR in WHERE condition

Tags: orchardcms, taxonomy

I am trying to filter the pages that a user sees by checking for common terms between the user and the page. Both the user and the page have a Taxonomy Field of the same type ("Category"), with terms "Standard" and "Premium".

If the category of the user matches with the category of the page, I want to display it, otherwise don't. This works fine with the following IHqlQuery on PagePart:

```
context.Query.Where(a => a.ContentPartRecord<TermsPartRecord>()
             .Property("Terms", "terms"), 
               x => x.InG("TermRecord.Id", ids));
```

where ids is the list of term ids of the user.

Apart from the above criteria, I also want to display pages that have no terms attached. This works fine on its own by:

```
context.Query.Where(a => a.ContentPartRecord<TermsPartRecord>(),
            x => x.IsEmpty("Terms")
```

The problem is when I try to combine the above two conditions. I have tried:

```
context.Query.Where(a => a.ContentPartRecord<TermsPartRecord>()
             .Property("Terms", "terms"), 
               p => p.Or(x => x.InG("TermRecord.Id", ids), y => y.IsEmpty("Terms")));
```

The second condition in the Or statement doesn't work because the query is already inside the Terms collection.

I have also tried:

```
context.Query.Where(a => a.ContentPartRecord<TermsPartRecord>()              
                p => p.Or(x => x.InG("Terms.TermRecord.Id", ids), y => y.IsEmpty("Terms")));
```

Here, the first condition is wrong, as I can't access an element of the Terms list with "Terms.TermRecord". This is as far as my Hql capabilities go. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I'm not all that familiar Orchard's query APIs, I always found them tough to use for more complex queries. You could always use raw HQL.

```
select distinct civ.Id
from Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentItemVersionRecord civ
join civ.ContentItemRecord ci
join ci.ContentType ct
left outer join ci.TermsPartRecord tpr
left outer join tpr.Terms terms
where ct.Name = 'Page' AND (terms.TermRecord.Id in (:ids) OR size(tpr.Terms) = 0)
```